# drop a pin when user touch screen in google maps swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want to add and remove `Marker`(pin) in Google Maps.

I want to drop pin with long touch and remove it. I want to use it to select my destination. How can I do it?

```
let  position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(10, 10)
let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
marker.map = mapView
```

Answer (score 6):

For the ones who're looking for a complete code snippet using **Swift**:

1. Implement Protocol `GMSMapViewDelegate`
2. Drag an Instance of GMSMapView `@IBOutlet weak var googleMapView: GMSMapView!`
3. Mention GMSMapView Delegate within `viewDidLoad()` as `googleMapView.delegate = self`
4. Implement the `didTapAt` delegate function:

`func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D){
        print("You tapped at \(coordinate.latitude), \(coordinate.longitude)")
        googleMapView.clear() // clearing Pin before adding new
        let marker = GMSMarker(position: coordinate)
        marker.map = googleMapView
    }`

Answer (score 4):

This code should help you!

```
//MARK: GMSMapViewDelegate Implimentation.
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapAt coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    plotMarker(AtCoordinate: coordinate, onMapView: mapView)
}

//MARK: Plot Marker Helper
private func plotMarker(AtCoordinate coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D, onMapView vwMap : GMSMapView) {
    let marker = GMSMarker(position: coordinate)
    marker.map = vwMap
}
```

**PS:** Dont forget to confirm to `GMSMapViewDelegate` in `ViewController` and assign `googleMap.delegate = self` somewhere in `viewDidLoad()`

Hope that helps!